# ajax call failed for Html returned as string from server

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I made an ajax call from jQuery to get the html as string from server.
The response is coming fine, how ever the ajax call goes to error handled saying there is some parseeorror.

Below the response I got from server:

```
 " <div class="spt4 d2-ugrid col-md-12" data-group="d1img" data-mailbox="browser"> <input name="VwAppRelPath" type="hidden" value="~/Views/Shared/generic/list/_generic_table_.cshtml" /> <h2>browse</h2> <ul> <li class="directories"> <a class="imagefolder" id="b1" title="b1">b1</a> </li> <li class="directories"> <a class="imagefolder" id="b2" title="b2">b2</a> </li> </ul> </div> "
```

Controller parses the view results as stirng:

```
return Content(base.View2String("browse", vm , ref info2use));
```

ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
            data: { "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest" },
            datatype: "json",
            url: "/i/d1img/browse?SiteDefID=309&ControlID=4359&CustomerID=1511&browserPath=" + subfolder + "&isAjax=true",
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                self._swapHtml(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, errorThrown, excepObj) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

Error details:

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 3 column 1 of the JSON data
return window.JSON.parse( data );

can somebody advise?

Comment: I replaced function parameters as function (results) and it worked fine..

Answer (score 0):

since you specified `dataType:"json"`, the ajax expects a json result from server whereas your server returns html

The solution would be to let ajax identify the type of the return data by itself. Remove the dataType attribute from your request.

Comment: The Html is returned as string. Please see updated response in question. Though we remove datatype, I am still getting the same parse error.

Comment: could it be that the double quotes are not escaped?

Comment: The parameter data is empty. It is not being filled. Any idea what could be the reason?